# Sum of value using condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this. Now i want two sum(hour).. 1 for place_type '1' and another for place_type '2'. Is it possible in mysql?

Now my query is

```
SELECT sum(hour) as totalHour from category_data group by category_data.user_id
```

also tried with IF condition but not working

```
SELECT IF(place_type='1',sum(hour),0) home, 
  IF(place_type='2', sum(hour), 0) center,
    from category_data group by category_data.user_id

user_id   place_type  hour     
  1          1         2
  1          2         5
  2          1         3
  2          2         4
  3          1         2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have an answer like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is what you need here.

```
select sum(case when place_type = 1 then `hour` end), 
       sum(case when place_type = 2 then `hour` end)
  from category_data
```

[Example fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d325/2)